# Powershell For Loop for multiple servers

Tags: powershell, api

```
$SM_Module_username = "admin"
$SM_Module_password = "xxxxxx"
$user = $SM_Module_username
$pass= $SM_Module_password
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$global:credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)
$expand_query ='?$expand=*($levels=1)'
$smmip = "172.128.35.56"

$uri = "https://$smmip/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1"
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -ErrorVariable RespErr -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json"}
$get_host = $result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$get_host.HostName

$uri = "https://$smmip/redfish/v1/UpdateService/FirmwareInventory$expand_query"
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -ErrorVariable RespErr -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json"}
$get_fw_inventory = $result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$get_fw_inventory.Members | Where-Object {($_.Id -like "Installed*") -and ($_.Name -eq "Integrated Remote Access Controller")} | select Name, Version
```

Although the above code works, I'd like to have this run against multiple servers using Powershell `PSVersion 5.1.14409.1018`. Could someone help me modify the script with `foreach` loop and `hashtable`, please? It'd be helpful to have the below output.

```
Host        Name                                Version
----        ----                                -------
Host1       Integrated Remote Access Controller 2.70.70.70
Host2       Integrated Remote Access Controller 2.60.60.60
Host3       Integrated Remote Access Controller 2.60.60.60
```

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'm running this against a physical component (Service Management Module) and connect to it using the REST API to collect a specific information. Do you think `Invoke-Command` with  `-ComputerName`will be able to connect to the physical module?

Comment: Are the passwords the same to all of the servers? If so, you only need to create an array of IPs -> `$smmips = "172.128.35.56","172.128.35.57","172.128.35.58"`. Then perform a `foreach ($smmip in $smmips) { # Your Invoke-WebReqest Code }`. Does this make sense and seem like it would work?

Comment: Even though the passwords are same, there are two different REST API calls are made for every IP, which make the `foreach` output a little bit messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine the results of the 2 API calls, you can iterate a list of servers like this:

```
# create an array op server IPs
$servers = "172.128.35.56","172.128.35.57","172.128.35.58"

$SM_Module_username = "admin"
$SM_Module_password = "xxxxxx"
$user = $SM_Module_username
$pass= $SM_Module_password
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$global:credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)
$expand_query ='?$expand=*($levels=1)'

foreach ($smmip in $servers) {
    $uri = "https://$smmip/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1"
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -ErrorVariable RespErr -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json"}
    $get_host = $result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    # remember this for constructing the PSObject later
    $hostname = $get_host.HostName

    $uri = "https://$smmip/redfish/v1/UpdateService/FirmwareInventory$expand_query"
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -ErrorVariable RespErr -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json"}
    $get_fw_inventory = $result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $get_fw_inventory.Members | Where-Object {($_.Id -like "Installed*") -and ($_.Name -eq "Integrated Remote Access Controller")} | ForEach-Object {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Host    = $hostname
            Name    = $_.Name
            Version = $_.version
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Spot on. You perfectly pictured the output I wanted. Thanks for your help @Theo

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a different API for each server, I would make a hashtable with the IP's/servers as the key, and use a simple array of IP's to retrieve the values and specifiy your target

```
$ApiTable = @{"10.10.10.10" = "api/for/server1"; "20.20.20.20" = "api/for/server2"; "30.30.30.30" = "api/for/server3"}

$Servers = ("10.10.10.10","20.20.20.20","30.30.30.30")

foreach($Server in $Servers)
{
    $uri = "https://$Server/$ApiTable.$Server"
}
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood your last comment on your original question... let me know if this isn't what you meant.

Comment: True, that was not what I meant. But that's alright, I appreciate your response. What matters is the intention to help :-) @Theo scripted it exactly the way I needed the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
# You will need to provide your IPs or FQDNs for your hosts below
$RespErr = $null
$smmips = '172.128.35.56','172.128.35.57','172.128.35.58','172.128.35.59'
$SM_Module_username = "admin"
$SM_Module_password = "xxxxxx"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $SM_Module_password -AsPlainText -Force
$global:credential = [pscredential]::new($SM_Module_username, $secpasswd)
$expand_query ='?$expand=*($levels=1)'

foreach ($smmip in $smmips) {
    $hosturi = "https://$smmip/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1"
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $hosturi -Credential $credential -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -ErrorVariable +RespErr -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json"}
    $get_host = $result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    $inventoryuri = "https://$smmip/redfish/v1/UpdateService/FirmwareInventory$expand_query"
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $inventoryuri -Credential $credential -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -ErrorVariable +RespErr -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json"}
    $get_fw_inventory = $result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $get_fw_inventory.Members |
        Where-Object {$_.Id -like "Installed*" -and $_.Name -eq "Integrated Remote Access Controller"} |
            Select-Object @{n='Host';e={$get_host.HostName}},Name, Version
}
```

**Explanation:**

The only varying input here are the IPs of the servers. Therefore, we only need to loop through the IPs. The body of the loop contains only the evaluated expressions that would vary for each IP.

Using the `foreach` loop, we iterate over the collection `$smmips` with each current item being `$smmip`.

Since you only want one output with three properties per iteration, we only output data with the final `Select-Object`. In order to incorporate a `Host` property from a previous expression, we use a calculated property called `Host`.

I added your error variable `$RespErr` to the beginning of the script to initialize it as `$null`. Using the syntax `-ErrorVariable +RespErr` will make `$RespErr` a collection of errors (if there are any) from potentially any of the hosts' responses.

Comment: Perfect. This one works too. It gives exactly the same output as Theo's. Thanks for your help and explanation @AdminOfThings. It makes things easier and comfortable.